# Batch delete subfolder if exist

Tags: batch-file

Im desesperate for help... im trying to make simply delete search folder if exist on batch.

batch file:

```
@for %%i in (C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) DO @if exist %%i: @for /d /r "%%i:\" %%a in (program\logs\) do if exist "%%a" echo rmdir /s /q "%%a"
```

but the result is not correct

```
if exist "C:\%i:\program\logs\" echo rmdir /s /q "C:\%i:\program\logs\"
```

Answer (score 1):

Well- known bug with `for /r` - the directory root provided before the `%%a` may not be a metavariable (ie the control variable from an outer loop)

Possible workaround (untried)

```
for %%i in (C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) DO if exist %%i: call :sub "%%i"
....
goto :eof

:sub
set "targetdir=%~1"
for /d /r "%targetdir%" %%a in (program\logs\) do if exist "%%a" echo rmdir /s /q "%%a"
goto :eof
```

the `goto :eof` (where the colon is **required**) jumps over the remainder of the code in the file. `CALL`ing the subroutine supplies "%%i" as the first parameter to the subroutine `:sub` (the quotes are not required in this case - but would be if the string being passed contained separators)

`:sub` sets a variable to the contents of the first parameter supplied; the `~` removes the quotes. Since batch replaces `%var%` with the contents of the variable as part of the parsing operation, it should make the appropriate substitution.

BTW  - a `@echo off` statement at the start of a batch makes `@` redundant within the file (`@` means "don't `echo` this statement before execution)

Comment: Any Workaround?

Comment: I'd call the issue a limitation, not a bug.

Comment: @dbenham : a quirk?